# Get child elements of element type

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a table with id `tableDiv`. I need to select each table header and data cells and dynamically reset their values, but because the table is made with ASP.NET (GridView) I can't set classes for headers and data elements.

I know to set CSS I can do this:

```
vpw = $(window).width();

$('#tableDiv').css({ 'width': vpw * 0.95 });
```

But how would I select it out for headers and data cells within the table?

Comment: Look up jQuery selectors.  They're quite versatile. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

For Header:

```
$('#tableDiv th:nth-child(i)').html("New Value");
```

For Cell:

```
$('#tableDiv tr:nth-child(i) td:nth-child(i)').html("New Value");
```

*`i` will be the child number you want to select*